# Why json file is giving unexpected enfd of string waring?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm not used to working on `json` files. As shown in the image below, when I copy the content in `PublicPem` field of `json` file, it shows red curly lines at three places, and gives me the warning `Unexpected end of string`. **Question**: How can we fix this error - and  what's the cause of the error?

[image]

Comment: The image can be supplementary, but please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75728565/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked to make sure there's no new line characters? Paste the JSON into a text editor and make sure it is plain text with no unprintable characters, like newline. Since your publicPem entry is so neatly formatted and your privatePem entry goes past, I bet this is the problem and hence the unterminated string error.

You could also try pasting the JSON into [an online JSON formatter.](https://jsonformatter.org/)

p.s. Next time asking a question like this, post the text and not an image. Then someone who answers the question could actually check that for you.

Comment: I used `notpad++` to remove line breaks (thank you).

Answer (score 2):

You have newlines in the middle of a string:

```js
JSON.parse(`{"id": "hello
world");
```

It needs to be a single line:

```js
JSON.parse(`{"id": "hello world"}`);
```

Or, (depending on how you implement it), you *may* be able to do:

```js
JSON.parse(`{"id": "hello \
world"}`);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge so other users can benefit, as well (my upvote). Your suggestions should work.